# ​ ValueError: Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs). Please use `Model.compile(…, run_eagerly=True)

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

I’ve been training an Image Classifier that can detect Oil and Pencil Paintings. While doing so I encountered a value error. I searched the web thoroughly unfortunately, I didn’t find any satisfactory answer as there was not much discussion about it.

Code:

```py
    import tensorflow as tf
    import os
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
    for gpu in gpus:
    
      tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
    len(gpus)
    
    # Data Generator
    IMAGE_SHAPE = (224, 224)
    TRAINING_DATA = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Datasets/train'
    
    
    VALID_DATA = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Datasets/test'
    
    datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    
        rescale=1./225
    
    )
    
    train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    
        TRAINING_DATA,
    
        shuffle=True,
    
        target_size=IMAGE_SHAPE,
    
    )
    
    valid_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    
        VALID_DATA,
    
        shuffle=False,
    
        target_size = IMAGE_SHAPE,
    
    )
    
    def build_model(num_classes):
    
      model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    
                                   tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=8, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu',
    
                                                          input_shape=(224, 224, 3)),
    
                                   tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=2),
    
                                   tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'),
    
                                   tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2),
    
                                   tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'),
    
                                   tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2),
    
                                   tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    
                                   tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    
                                   tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')
    
                                   
    
      ])
    
      return model
    
    model = build_model(num_classes=2)
    
    model.compile(
    
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001),
    
        loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    
        metrics=['accuracy']
    
    )
    
    print(model.summary())
```

**Error Code:**

```
EPOCHS = 20

BATCH_SIZE = 32

history = model.fit(train_generator,

                    steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples // BATCH_SIZE, 

                    epochs=EPOCHS,

                    validation_data=valid_generator,

                    validation_steps=valid_generator.samples // BATCH_SIZE,

                    verbose=1

                    )

   1393         logs = tf_utils.sync_to_numpy_or_python_type(logs)
   1394         if logs is None:
-> 1395           raise ValueError('Unexpected result of `train_function` '
   1396                            '(Empty logs). Please use '
   1397                            '`Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or '

ValueError: Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` for more information of where went wrong, or file a issue/bug to `tf.keras`.
```

I've seen some other Stack Overflow answers where they mentioned `set input_shape=3`, which I already had by default in my code still I was having this error. I saw some GitHub error reports about it but there was no solution available. By the way, I'm using the latest version of Tensorflow and TensorGPU, and Keras. If someone could help me to understand what went wrong that would be awesome cuz at the moment I don't know whether it's a bug in Keras or a fault in my code.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue a lot of times, and every time it occurred because of the wrong dataset directory. You can set a full dataset directory path when importing data, like this if you're using Mac:

```
'/Users/<path to dataset>
```

Or just copy path from files and paste it in the code.